# Display a formatted text in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a simple HTML (copy/paste from printable version of some Wikipedia page) and I wanna show it in my app.

Is there any way to convert it to a **more native XAML look** rather than just showing the whole page in a `WebView`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129(v=vs.90).aspx should be a good start for you

Comment: unfortunately, metro does not support FlowDocument.

Comment: Can you just grab (scrape) the text in the pages <p> tags and flip it into a textblock(s)?

Comment: Yeah, but I have preserve all the formats myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML and format a TextBlock or RichTextBlock. You can check out the [RichTextBlockExtensions.LinkedHtmlFragment](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/79db4cb8e6f7#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/RichTextBlockExtensions.cs) I wrote for a sample of how you might go about adding some text with links to a RichTextBlock, but this only supports plain text with some basic anchor tags. Anything more would require more work and I haven't come across any open source library that would do it for you, since you would likely need to have custom styling for a limited set of pages. Otherwise - writing a generic HTML to XAML converter is probably an effort similar to implementing a new web browser.